# Angular 2 - How to return actual data from observable using a middle layer

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a scenario where I have an http service which returns the `Observable<any>` and I can `subscribe` it inside my components and get the returned data. This is just the normal stuff but I have few functions that needs to be called from every component and I don't want to write the repeated subscribe code just everywhere.

So I'm looking for a way to add a centralized layer which will be responsible for accepting the observable from service and return the data (not observable) which can be directly used by the components to clean up the code. But when I do that, the else part executes and I get the null (as expected in asynchronous calls).

Example:

In http service:

```
public getHighestBid(id: string): Observable<Bid> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    var api: string = '/Auction';
    var url: string = BaseConfigurations.baseApiPath + api + '/' + id;
    let response = this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    return response;
}
```

In middle layer:

```
public getHighestBid(id: string): Bid {
    this.liveService.getHighestBid(id).subscribe(highestBid => {
        return highestBid;  //this returns results asynchronously which is expected
    }, error => { });
    return null;    //this executes first, how can I wait for above call to finish first?
}
```

In my components, I just want to call this middle layer and get the result without having to subscribe.

```
let bid: Bid = this.Service.getHighestBid(id); //this gets 2 responses, one null and then the original response..
```

I want to call this function from multiple places if possible.

Comment: You dont need to subscribe in controller. You can just say `stream$ | async` . Even without that , subscribe is way simpler than callbacks . Any code to make simpler only complicates it

Comment: @Skeptor Can you add some reference link or example?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe